# slackbots npm package returning SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: node.js, slack-api

The [Slackbots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slackbots) package stopped working for me without any modifications to my Node.js slack bot application. On start up I receive the error:

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

which is outputed from:

```
bot.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("error connecting to slack " + err);
});
```

using Node version 6.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the Slackbots package code I was able to get myself into reading about the Slack API method [rtm.start](https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.start) and in there I found the line saying

> Please use `rtm.connect` instead, especially when connecting on behalf of an [Enterprise Grid](https://api.slack.com/enterprise-grid) customer.

Since I am an Enterprise Grid customer I changed the line in `index.js` for the Slackbot package to the following

`this._api('rtm.start').then...` to `this._api('rtm.connect').then...` and everything started working again.